# What is the best way to host a web app for a marketer?

Tags: hosting, spam, suspend

I have recently developed a web app for a marketer that he has been sending emails to his potential customers to fill out an application form existing in this web app.

Recently, I received an email from his hosting company saying that they will suspend his account because his emails were triggered by SpamCop.

What would be the best way to handle this situation?

Thank you,

Niyazi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first - WHY were they marked by spamcop? From what you told us in the header, your customer is SCUM (i.e. a spammer, breaking the law). In this case he has to stop that. He may think he is a valid marketer, but most likely he is not.

WHat is the difference? Well, where did the emails come from? I gues he purchased them - or collected them. So, sending them email is illegal ;) DOes he follow protocol? As in: Send with his own domain as sender, check for bounces, have a sign out link and for starters make sure people ASKED VALIDLY FOR INFORMATION FIRST?

I get a lot of marketing emails daily, and I never complained because I signed up and I can get out "fast" with one click if I have to.

Unless you handle all that, every other ISP is going to do the same - thrw you out as soon as they realize waht you do.